# Python, pd dataframe extract values based on condition raises error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe of nba player stats:

```py
print(self.df)


                                                      Name   PTS   REB  AST  \
(updated to: , 2020-02-24 19:39:00)                                           
0                                             James Harden  35.2   6.4  7.4   
1                                    Giannis Antetokounmpo  30.0  13.6  5.8   
2                                               Trae Young  30.0   4.4  9.2   
3                                             Bradley Beal  29.6   4.4  6.0   
4                                           Damian Lillard  29.5   4.4  7.9   
...                                                    ...   ...   ...  ...   
261                                        Jerome Robinson   3.1   1.7  1.1   
262                                           Goga Bitadze   3.1   2.0  0.5   
263                                          Javonte Green   3.0   1.7  0.5   
264                                           Semi Ojeleye   2.9   1.9  0.5   
265                                    Matthew Dellavedova   2.5   1.1  2.6   

                                     STL  BLK   FGM   FGA   FG%  3PM   3PA  \
(updated to: , 2020-02-24 19:39:00)                                          
0                                    1.7  1.0  10.1  23.1  43.9  4.6  12.8   
1                                    1.1  1.1  11.1  20.1  55.2  1.5   4.8   
2                                    1.2  0.1   9.3  20.8  44.5  3.5   9.5   
3                                    1.1  0.4  10.1  22.2  45.3  2.6   8.0   
4                                    1.0  0.3   9.4  20.4  46.0  3.9  10.0   
...                                  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   
261                                  0.3  0.2   1.2   3.5  34.1  0.5   1.7   
262                                  0.1  0.7   1.3   2.6  48.2  0.1   0.6   
263                                  0.5  0.1   1.2   2.3  51.1  0.1   0.6   
264                                  0.3  0.1   1.0   2.4  39.5  0.5   1.5   
265                                  0.3  0.0   0.9   2.7  32.3  0.2   1.4   

                                      3P%   FTM   FTA   FT%  
(updated to: , 2020-02-24 19:39:00)                          
0                                    35.9  10.4  12.0  86.8  
1                                    31.1   6.4  10.4  61.5  
2                                    37.4   7.9   9.3  85.5  
3                                    32.0   6.9   8.1  84.4  
4                                    39.3   6.8   7.7  88.9  
...                                   ...   ...   ...   ...  
261                                  29.5   0.3   0.4  57.1  
262                                  15.4   0.5   0.7  69.0  
263                                  26.1   0.6   0.9  63.9  
264                                  35.0   0.5   0.5  88.9  
265                                  15.9   0.5   0.6  89.3  

[266 rows x 15 columns]
```

I'm trying to analyze some stats by narrowing down the df and get all stats above two column's mean, and when trying to extract some values based on condition, I get the following error.

```py
    def get_stat(self):
        pts_fgm_df = self.df.head(n=120)
        rslt_df = pts_fgm_df.loc[pts_fgm_df['PTS'] > pts_fgm_df['PTS'].mean() & pts_fgm_df['FG%'] > pts_fgm_df.mean()]
        print(rslt_df)
```

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: I assume that you are missing some brackets around your boolean expressions: `rslt_df = (pts_fgm_df.loc[pts_fgm_df['PTS'] > pts_fgm_df['PTS'].mean()) & (pts_fgm_df['FG%'] > pts_fgm_df.mean()])`. Operator precedence would otherwise try to evaluate the & first.

Answer (score 0):

My solution eventuality:

```py
        top_df = self.df.head(n=120)
        mean_pts = top_df['PTS'].mean()
        mean_fgp = top_df['FG%'].mean()
        rslt_df = top_df[
            (top_df['PTS'] >= mean_pts) &
            (top_df['FG%'] >= mean_fgp)
            ]
        return rslt_df
```

My problem was when I wrote the logic it wasn't clear to watch.

```py
# So the solution is to first give every statement a variable name.
mean_pts = top_df['PTS'].mean()
mean_fgp = top_df['FG%'].mean()
pts = top_df['PTS']
fgp = top_df['FG%']
```

then filter based on them:

```py
# Which makes this a lot clearer to see missing brackets and such.
rslt_df = top_df[
            (pts >= mean_pts) &
            (fgp >= mean_fgp)
            ]
return rslt_df
```

Comment: Please explain in words your solution for future readers. Code only answers are discouraged.